# Certificate Setup Over Many Remote Resources

Tags: certificates

Imagine that you have a web app that needs to talk to a central api server with its purchased certificate. This server provides a token to the web app to be used to authenticate and talk to another remote resource (another api server of our own). The remote resource can change anytime and can not hold the certificate of the central api server for security purposes but it must talk over https with the web app.

I have not tried this setup but do I need a purchased certificate for each of those remote servers (there could be many of them) so that the browser allow a https connection to them without complaining about the fact that it would not know their CA or can I manage this with self-sign certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You can add - inside your app - a trusted certificate to the chain, and you can use a self-sustaining private CA. Even more I'm encouraging you to do so because of security, encode a key's checksums inside your app and verify them too.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you please point me to anywhere with more details? Do I need to host my own CA? When you say App, do you the web app or api server? If web app, how do I add a trusted certificate to the chain with javascript? Also, can I add a trusted certificate to the chain per connection and based on the remote resource that the connection want to access?

Comment: @iCode You better host your own CA with CRL's, but it's not a requirement unless you're using a client keys. When I'm talking about "an App" I mean a client-side standalone app, and via JavaScript it's 100% possible in Firefox addons : take a look [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cacert-root-certificate/) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690980/firefox-estensions-programmatically-add-a-certificate-to-the-trust-certificate), so you can try a per-connection adding, I suppose(but I've never used it in per-connection scope, so you better try yourself).

Comment: @iCode about untrustworthiness of a centralized CA's take a read [here](http://convergence.io/details.html) and make sure you watch the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Wl2FW2TcA)